# Weird behavior of computing sum of two random variables using TransformedDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I want to calculate the p.d.f of two discrete random variables. However, when I made a toy example that random variable was `dist` and I wanted to find p.d.f. of `dist+dist`, it failed.

```
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[{2/9, 5/9, 2/9} -> {-1, 0, 1}];
ya[t_] := PDF[TransformedDistribution[2*x, {x \[Distributed] dist}], t];
ya /@ Range[-10, 10]
(*Output: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2/9, 0, 5/9, 0, 2/9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

The output seems wrong, because the p.d.f. of the sum of two random variables should be the convolution of these two. Hence the correct answer should be
[image]

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: There's a difference between taking the sum of two independent r.v. and multiplying a r.v. by two. The latter is essentially equivalent to adding two perfectly correlated r.v. together. Mathematica's result is correct here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method generalises easily to larger sums:

```
k = 2;
vec = Array[x, k];
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[{2/9, 5/9, 2/9} -> {-1, 0, 1}];
pdf = PDF @ TransformedDistribution[
   Total[vec],
   vec \[Distributed] ProductDistribution[
     {dist, k}
     ]
   ]
DiscretePlot[pdf[n], {n, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two random variables, x and y, each with the same distribution:

```
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[{2/9, 5/9, 2/9} -> {-1, 0, 1}];
ya[t_] := PDF[TransformedDistribution[x + y, 
    {x \[Distributed] dist, y [Distributed] dist}], t];
ya /@ Range[-10, 10]
(*Output:{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4/81,20/81,11/27,20/81,4/81,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}*)
```